# How to direct wordpress traffic to specific page

Tags: plugins

I have a page created in wordpress that I want to redirect all users to. Ex.: www.mywordpress.com/offline

How can I direct all traffic requests (except wp-admin and dashboard) to this page?

My goal is to have an offline page for when I am working on things or I am not accepting any new business.

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/jf3-maintenance-mode/

This plugin is intended primarily for designers / developers that need to allow clients to preview sites before being available to the general public or to temporarily hide your WordPress site while undergoing major updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `template_redirect` action for redirect all user to specific page. paste this code in functions.php of active theme and just change page slug `offline` with your page slug where you want to redirect. when non logged user visit any page of site it will redirect to specific page.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );
function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if ( !is_page('offline') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url()."/offline/" ); 
        exit();
    }
}
```